# Add a property to an object (or at least similar outcome)

Tags: dart

First, the context of what I'm doing.  I am running an HttpServer which is handling HttpRequests.

```dart
    HttpServer.bind(ADDRESS, PORT).then((HttpServer server) {
      listenSubscription = server.listen(onRequest);
    });

    void onRequest(HttpRequest request) {
      //handle request here
    }
```

I'd like to add some logging to all this, and due to the asynchronous nature of it all, want to add some identifying marker to the requests (so I can match up the request receipts with the responses, fer example).  The code inside of `onRequest()` calls a bunch of other functions to do different things (handle GET vs POST requests, etc.), so simply generating an id at the top is a cumbersome solution as I'd have to pass it around through all those other function calls.  I am, however, already passing around the `HttpRequest` object, so I thought it would be nice to throw an `id` field on it, just like you would in Javascript, except that Dart doesn't work that way.

Thoughts then went to subclassing the `HttpRequest` class, but converting the `HttpRequest` object the `onRequest()` method receives seemed like much more trouble and overhead than my needs required.

So I ask, is there any idiomatic Dart way attach some data to an existing object?  If there isn't something idiomatic, what is the simplest (both in code and runtime complexity) way you can think of to accomplish this?

Comment: You can create a map with object as key and value as attached data. Not pretty, but simple.

Comment: A map was something I had considered, but would require manual garbage cleaning which made me want to find something better.  Seems the `Expando` (see accepted answer) is more or less the same thing, but with automatic cleanup and wrapped in a pretty package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there's an [Expando](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.Expando), but I don't know the performance implications.

Something like:

```dart
// somewhere top level. Create this once.
final loggingId = new Expando();
...
// inside of onRequest
loggingId[request] = generateId();
...
// later inside log()
print(loggingId[request]);
```

Expandos are like weak-reference maps, from my understanding.

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for pointing this class out to me Seth, I had no clue it existed.  I ended up adding two Expandos to the server, one to track request id, and another to attach a `Stopwatch` so I could also log the response times.